# General closed form solution to $f'(x) = P(f(x))/P(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, function-and-relation-composition

Does there exist a general closed form solution (in terms of elementary or special functions) to the differential equation:

$$ \frac{df(x)}{dx} = \frac{P(f(x))}{P(x)} $$

when $P(x)$ is a polynomial of degree higher than 3? (excluding the trivial case $f(x)=x$).

---

Context:

I'm trying to find the action of a certain class of composition operators

$$C_f(x,\frac{d}{dx}) = e^{P(x) \frac{d}{dx}} $$

where $P(x)$ is a polynomial in $\mathbb{C}$ of degree $n \geq 3$, such that for a complex function $g$

$$C_f(g) = g \circ f$$

After some manipulations, one arrives at the Abel equation

$$ f(x) = \alpha^{-1}(\alpha(x) + 1) $$

where

$$ \alpha(x) = \int^x \frac{dt}{P(t)} $$

Differentiating this last expression, one obtains a differential equation that all the family of iterations of $f$ (even fractional ones) must satisfy:

$$ \frac{df(x)}{dx} = \frac{P(f(x))}{P(x)} $$

I already know the basic properties of this function, and I know how to calculate it numerically. What I'm trying to find is whether there exists a general closed form expression for $f$ when $\deg P \geq 3$ (in the case $n \leq 2$, $f(x)$ is a Möbius transformation).

There are some special cases I've checked manually, such as the case $P(x) = ax^n$, whose solution is a combination of a rational function and radicals, but I don't know if this holds in general, or how to prove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After revisiting my question I think I found an answer. Let $P(x)$ be a monic polynomial of degree $3$ for simplicity, and furthermore, let two of its roots be $0$ and $1$, and the third one be real. This polynomial can thus be put in the form:

$$P(x)=x(x-1)(x-r)$$

where $r\neq 0, 1$ is the third root.

The problem then reduces to finding the explicit form of an inverse function of

$$\int^x \frac{dt}{P(t)} = \frac1{r(r-1)} \left( (r-1) \log x - r \log(1-x) + \log(x-r)\right) = \alpha(x)$$

Between two of the logarithmic singularities the function (regarded as a real function) is one-to-one, so an inverse exists. Grouping the logarithms and simplifying, we obtain

$$\alpha(x) = \frac1{r(1-r)} \log \left( \frac{(\frac1x-1)^r} {1-\frac rx} \right) $$

To find the inverse, we must solve (setting $z = \frac1x$):

$$y = \frac{(z-1)^r} {1- rz}$$

for $z$ in terms of $y$. If $r$ is a natural number this is equivalent to solving a polynomial equation of degree $r$, and we know from Galois theory that there isn't a general closed form algebraic solution except when $r<5$. If $r$ is irrational the situation is even worse.

So it looks like the answer to my question is **no**, except in some special cases. There is still the possibility that although the inverse function $\alpha^{-1}(x)$ isn't expressible in closed form, its composition with $\alpha(x) + c$, where $c\neq0$ is an appropriate constant, leads to a closed form expression, but it seems unlikely and I don't know how to explore that possibility anyways.

Answer (score 7):

These kinds of equations are ones where abuse of Leibniz notation works. We can write
$$\int\frac{1}{P(y)}dy=\int\frac{1}{P(x)}dx$$
Integrating and treating the constants correctly gives us the solution. Whether there is a closed form probably depends on the polynomial.

Comment: Not an abuse, just separation of variables ;)

Comment: @Evgeny It still is abuse of notation, since separation, done rigorously, does not actually work in the way that it is portrayed in this answer.